If $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)=O(x^{1/4})$, what can we say about the zeros of the Riemann zeta function?
The Riesz function is defined by
$$\operatorname{Riesz}(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1} x^k}{(k-1)!\zeta(2k)}$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. Marcel Riesz showed that the Riemann hypothesis (RH) is equivalent to the claim that for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)=O(x^{1/4+\varepsilon})$ as $x\to\infty$. Per Wikipedia, however, it has been shown that under RH, we actually have
$$\operatorname{Riesz}(x)\sim Kx^{1/4}\sin\left(\phi-\frac{1}{2}\gamma_1\log x\right)$$
where $K$ and $\phi$ are constants and $\gamma_1$ is the imaginary part of the first nontrivial zero of $\zeta$. Since $\sin$ is bounded, this seemingly gives $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)=O(x^{1/4})$, which is slightly better than the bound given by RH. Assuming $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)=O(x^{1/4})$ holds, could we say anything about the nontrivial zeros $\rho$ beyond $\operatorname{Re}\rho=1/2$?
My guess is that having $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)=O(x^{1/4})$ restricts the possible multiplicities of the zeros. Here are my reasons:

RH is equivalent to a bound where $\varepsilon=0$ would prove that the nontrivial zeros are all simple. Such a bound is referenced in the same paper cited above; it is $c_k=O(k^{-3/4+\varepsilon})$, where
$$c_k:=\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\frac{1}{\zeta(2j+2)}$$
This is not quite the same thing as $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)=O(x^{1/4+\varepsilon})$ as this involves a sequence and not a function, but I still find the analogy interesting.

Wikipedia derives the representation
$$\operatorname{Riesz}(z)=\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{\zeta(-2s)}z^{-s}ds \text{ $(-1<c<-1/2)$}$$
and states that if the Riemann hypothesis is true, then we can move the line of integration up to $c<-1/4$. I'd assume that the fourth-root rate of growth comes from $z^{-s}=z^{-{c-it}}$, so if $\operatorname{Riesz}(z)=O(z^{1/4})$, we might be able to integrate over $c=-1/4$ and conclude that the zeros of $\zeta$ correspond to integrable singularities in $\frac{1}{\zeta(-2s)}$, thus restricting their possible multiplicities.


Any help and feedback is appreciated.

If there is a zero of order $m \geq 2$, then $\mathrm{Riesz}(z) = \Omega(x^{1/4} (\log x)^{m - 1})$. You should read Chapter 15 of Montgomery-Vaughan (and then you should be able to prove this yourself).

Just looked up Wolf's paper cited and there is no proof of the assertion $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)\sim Kx^{1/4}\sin\left(\phi-\frac{1}{2}\gamma_1\log x\right)$ under RH; there is a more complicated expression and the author truncates it to this to approximate the Riesz function and check that under some computations for some values of $x$ so Wikipedia is wrong here

@Conrad just checked the paper and am now doubting Wikipedia's claim too, but something is confusing me. I think the more complicated expression you're referring to is eq. $(16)$, so the truncated expression would be eq. $(21)$ or the equivalent $(23)$. Why does dropping the terms with $l\geq 2$ not leave us with an asymptotic estimate?

@PeterHumphries how I’m understanding this: if $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)=O(x^{1/4})$ and $\operatorname{Riesz}(x)=\Omega(x^{1/4}(\log x)^{m-1})$, then we get $x^{1/4}(\log x)^{m-1}=O(x^{1/4})$, which is a contradiction unless $m=1$.

in order to get an asymptotic estimate, you would need to prove that the stuff that you drop is negligible wr to the remaining stuff and there is no proof for that (even for just a simple bound $|R(x)| << x^{1/4}$ you would need to show that the infinite sum is bounded uniformly and again there is no proof for that either)

Wikipedia is wrong. Wolf also has made several mistakes in his papers in the past, so I would read his paper with care.

@Conrad I see. Looks like I’ll need to be more careful about math claims on Wikipedia.

@PeterHumphries thank you for the heads up, I’ll be sure to do that. Also, since your first comment technically answers my question, I’d recommend promoting it to an answer. If you can, a sketch of the proof would be greatly appreciated; I don’t have a copy of Montgomery-Vaughan.
